# Change color of Vuetify checkbox in datatable header

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I want to customize the colors of Vuetify. So I am using slots of various components to do it. While I am able to achieve custom color for checkbox in header using `header.data-table-select` slot. The color of checkbox when only some of the rows are selected(but not all) is still grey. Can anyone suggest what I can do to customize its color.

[Link to codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-datatable-cutom-colors-6i54s)

#### Problem screenshot

[image: My issue with custom color]

#### Partially working

[image: Working only when all are selected]

Answer (score 1):

When value is false, v-simple-checkbox doesn't apply color.
but props.value become true only when all values are selected.

I think this way is better.

```
<template v-slot:[`header.data-table-select`]="{ props, on }">
      <v-simple-checkbox
        :value="props.value || props.indeterminate"
        v-on="on"
        :indeterminate="props.indeterminate"
        color="primary"
      />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it this way.

```
<template v-slot:header.data-table-select="{ props, on }">
        <v-simple-checkbox
          color="primary"
          v-if="props.indeterminate"
          v-ripple
          v-bind="props"
          :value="props.indeterminate"
          v-on="on"
        ></v-simple-checkbox>
        <v-simple-checkbox
          color="primary"
          v-if="!props.indeterminate"
          v-ripple
          v-bind="props"
          v-on="on"
        ></v-simple-checkbox>
      </template>
```